# c programming error in thread creation?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, timer

```
void *newThread(void *arg)
{
  makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
  makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
  makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
  return 0;
}


int CreateSocket()
{
  pthread_t tid;
  socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
  // Socket creation for UDP

  acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

  if (acceptSocket==-1)
  {
    printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Socket started!\n");
  }

  //non blocking mode
  /* rc = ioctl(acceptSocket, FIONBIO, (char *)&flag);
      if (rc < 0)
      {
                 printf("\n ioctl() failed \n");
         return 0;
      }*/

  //Bind the socket
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port=htons(port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
  if (rc== -1)
  {
    printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);
  }

  if (acceptSocket == -1)
  {
    printf("Fehler: accept, fehler code:\n");
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &newThread, NULL);

    while (rc!=-1)
    {
      rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);

      if (rc==0)
      {
        printf("Server has no connection..\n");
        break;
      }

      if (rc==-1)
      {
        printf("something went wrong with data %s", strerror(errno));
        break;
      }

      XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );
    }
  }

  close(acceptSocket);
  return 0;
}


int main()
{
  Xcp_Initialize();
  CreateSocket();
  return 0;
}
```

I am working on a client and server architecture. Server code is shown above and I created a socket to recieve the request from the client via the ip address and port number. Server is waiting for a request from the client and send a response back to the client. I also created timer to call te task for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. I created a seperated thread for calling the timer task. The thread is called while running after that it is not recieving any data from the client. What is the error ??

Comment: Does `recvfrom()` ever return?

Comment: when it recieves some data then there is a api called as XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port ); to do further sending of data automatically.

Comment: but in debug mode. It is stopped at pthread_create only.